# Shiny App R - Reactive variables not responding to change in Input variables

Tags: r, input, output, shiny

I'm making an app that will predict an NFL running back's number of rush attempts and rush yards AFTER a season of 1800+ rush yards.  I use slider inputs for the # of rushing yards and attempts, which gets run through lm() and predict() and returns estimates for next year's attempts and rush yards (I know it's not a very good predictor at all, but this is just an exercise in making a Shiny app).  Here's the data from my excel file and then the code.

```
Player  Yr. Team    Attempts    Att.Next.Yr Yards   Yards.Next.Yr   YPC YPC.Next.Yr
1   Adrian Peterson 2012    MIN 348 279 2097    1266    6.0 4.5
2   Chris Johnson   2009    TEN 358 316 2006    1364    5.6 4.3
3   LaDainian Tomlinson 2006    SD  348 315 1815    1474    5.2 4.7
4   Shaun Alexander 2005    SEA 370 252 1880    896 5.1 3.6
5   Tiki Barber 2005    NYG 357 327 1860    1662    5.2 5.1
6   Jamal Lewis 2003    BAL 387 235 2066    1006    5.3 4.3
7   Ahman Green 2003    GB  355 259 1883    1163    5.3 4.5
8   Ricky Williams  2002    MIA 383 392 1853    1372    4.8 3.5
9   Terrell Davis   1998    DEN 392 67  2008    211 5.1 3.1
10  Jamal Anderson  1998    ATL 410 19  1846    59  4.5 3.1
11  Barry Sanders   1997    DET 335 343 2053    1491    6.1 4.3
12  Barry Sanders   1994    DET 331 314 1883    1500    5.7 4.8
13  Eric Dickerson  1986    RAM 404 60  1821    277 4.5 4.6
14  Eric Dickerson  1984    RAM 379 292 2105    1234    5.6 4.2
15  Eric Dickerson  1983    RAM 390 379 1808    2105    4.6 5.6
16  Earl Campbell   1980    HOU 373 361 1934    1376    5.2 3.8
17  Walter Payton   1977    CHI 339 333 1852    1395    5.5 4.2
18  O.J. Simpson    1975    BUF 329 290 1817    1503    5.5 5.2
19  O.J. Simpson    1973    BUF 332 270 2003    1125    6.0 4.2
20  Jim Brown   1963    CLE 291 280 1863    1446    6.4 5.2
```

Server.R

```
# server.R

library(UsingR)
library(xlsx)
rawdata <- read.xlsx("RushingYards.xlsx", sheetIndex=1)

data <- rawdata[c(2:21),]
rownames(data) <- NULL

# Att
set.seed(1)
fitAtt <- lm(Att.Next.Yr ~ Yards + Attempts, data)

# Yds
set.seed(1)
fitYds <- lm(Yards.Next.Yr ~ Yards + Attempts, data)

shinyServer(
        function(input, output) {

            output$newPlot <- renderPlot({
                        iYards <- input$Yards
                        iAttempts <- input$Attempts

                        test <- data.frame(iYards,iAttempts)
                        names(test) <- c("Yards", "Attempts")
                        predictAtt <- predict(fitAtt, test)
                        predictYds <- predict(fitYds, test)

                        qplot(data=data, x=Attempts, y=Yards) + 
                            geom_point(aes(x=predictAtt, y=predictYds, color="Estimate"))

                        output$renderYds <- renderPrint({predictYds})

                        output$renderAtt <- renderPrint({predictAtt})

                  })


        }
)
```

UI.R

```
# ui.R

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
        headerPanel("Rushing Projections"),
        sidebarPanel(
                sliderInput('Yards', 'How many yards rushed for this season', 
                            value=1700, min=1500, max=2500, step=25,),
                sliderInput('Attempts', 'How many attempts this season',
                            value=350, min=250, max=450, step=5,),
                submitButton('Submit')

        ),
        mainPanel(
                plotOutput('newPlot'),
                h3('Predicted rushing yards next year: '),
                verbatimTextOutput("renderYds"),
                h3('Predict attempts next year: '),
                verbatimTextOutput("renderAtt")

        )
))
```

The problem I'm having is I can't seem to output BOTH the plot (next year's estimates plotted in red against historical performances for running backs > 1800 rush yards) and the text of next year's estimated rushing yards and attempts at the same time.  I can get one or the other to show up depending on where I put those statements.  If I put

```
output$renderYds <- renderPrint({predictYds})
output$renderAtt <- renderPrint({predictAtt})
```

outside of the output$newPlot (but still inside of function(input, output)) line I can get the plot to show up and the point for next year's estimates changes as the input is changed but I get error messages of

`object 'predictYds' not found'` and `object 'predictAtt' not found` for the text.  If I put those two lines inside of the `function(input, output)` line (as I have in the code above) then those two text numbers show up with the correct value but the plot doesn't generate.

Can anyone help with this please?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the structure of Server.R and now it works.

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

            predictYds <- function(Y, A){
                test <- data.frame(Y, A)
                names(test) <- c("Yards", "Attempts")
                predict(fitYds, test)
            }

            predictAtt <- function(Y, A){
                test <- data.frame(Y, A)
                names(test) <- c("Yards", "Attempts")
                predict(fitAtt, test)
            }

            output$newPlot <- renderPlot({

                        newYards <- predictYds(input$Yards, input$Attempts)
                        newAttempts <- predictAtt(input$Yards, input$Attempts)
                        qplot(data=data, x=Attempts, y=Yards) + 
                            geom_point(aes(x=newAttempts, y=newYards, color="Estimate"))

                  })

            output$renderYds <- renderPrint({predictYds(input$Yards, input$Attempts)})

            output$renderAtt <- renderPrint({predictAtt(input$Yards, input$Attempts)})
        }
)
```

Basically PredictYds and PredictAtt were rewritten as normal functions called inside render functions using input variables.